# Echo Schema with field that is both a primary key and a foreign key

Tags: elixir, ecto

My database design has two entities: Employee and Manager.
Manager ISA Employee.

This is how I defined the employees and managers table:

```
create table(:employees) do
end

create table(:managers, primary_key: false) do
        add :id, references(:employees, on_delete: :delete_all), primary_key: true
end
```

I am not sure how the MyApp.Manager module should go. If the id column was only a custom primary key, then it should be:

```
@primary_key {:id, :integer, []}
schema "managers" do
end
```

But how should I indicate that :id is both a primary key and a foreign key to the employee table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `belongs_to` macro has couple options, some of which can help you:

- the `foreign_key: :id` allows you to specify the foreign key name,
- you can also use the `define_field: false` option that will use an existing schema field for the foreign key and skip generating one on it's own.

The final `schema` declaration can look like this:

```
@primary_key {:id, :integer, []}
schema "managers" do
  belongs_to :employee, Employee, define_field: false, foreign_key: :id
end
```